# Operating System Concept, A Translation is need?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, translation, computing

Who can translate the following sentence in a simple manner?

> Between garbage collections free space will build up, which cannot be 
>   reclaimed until the next time the garbage collector runs. This is a
>   form of fragmentation.

Thanks to all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU is not a translation service

Comment: @Mitch please be patient to learn others.

Comment: user42...: Sure. I'm patiently trying to teach you that that you're using this site inappropriately.

Comment: No @Mitch I read a book and misunderstood one part. comes here ask others to learn.

Comment: @user4249446, can you be a little more specific about what is giving you trouble with this sentence?  A blanket statement like "I don't understand it" doesn't give us enough to go on to figure out how to help you.  As it is, the question is not clear enough for us to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Hellion Is as: 
a) If a memory allocation mechanism uses a compacting garbage collector for reclamation then it does not experience fragmentation
Answer: false. Between garbage collections free space will build up, which cannot be reclaimed until the next time the garbage collector runs. This is a form of fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated to program objects which are now out of scope does not become available until that space is reclaimed by periodic garbage collection.  The total free memory area is fragmented by these sections of memory which are candidates for garbage collection, but not yet returned to the free area.

build up = accumulate, grow in number

fragmentation == disrupted contiguity

reclaimed = returned to the pool of free memory (i.e. free=available for use by new program objects)

Comment: I think another translation is correct ! am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You wanted it simplified?
Between passes of the garbage collector, fragments of free space accumulate. On the next pass of the garbage collector, it consolidates these fragments. Only then does the free space become usable.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection  is like the process of recycling plastic for example. Once the bottle of pop has been consumed, the plastic bottle it came in  is (temporarily) redundant. The garbage collector comes along, picks the bottle up, cleans it and makes a brand new plastic bottle from it.

HTH:)

Comment: I know it, but about sentence, it was a problem. see my last comment